# You cannot modify child views while in the inBuffer state in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

In my ember app(version 1.9.1 - EAK), I have something in a hbs file like,

```
{{#each obj.obj1}} 

 {{#view "selection" model = this}}
 ---------some code-------
 {{/view}}

{{/each}}
```

That's working fine. If I change it like this,

```
{{#each item in obj.obj1}} 

 {{#view "selection" model = this}}
 ---------some code-------
 {{/view}}

{{/each}}
```

am getting the error "You cannot modify child views while in the inBuffer state in ember".

Comment: Changed "model = item" and it worked. Add your comment as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually means that something went horribly wrong. For instance, your view might not be correctly derived from `Ember.View`.

However, in this particular case, you want `model=item` instead of `model=this`. The `{{#each..in}}` form does not set `this`. `this` will still be what it was outside the loop.